# $f_n\rightharpoonup f$ in $H^1\Rightarrow f_n\to f$ in $L^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

I am trying to show the following:

> Denote $L^2=L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $H^1=H^1(\mathbb{R}^d)=\{f\in{\cal S}';\sqrt{1-\Delta}f\in L^2\}$. Let $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset H^1$ and let $f\in H^1$.
>   If
>   $$f_n\rightharpoonup f\ {\rm in}\ H^1\ {\rm as}\ n\to\infty,$$
>   then
>   $$f_n\to f\  {\rm in}\ L^2\ {\rm as}\ n\to\infty.$$

Here is my attempt.
Since $L^2\subset H^{-1}$, I can get $f_n\rightharpoonup f$ in $L^2$ as $n\to\infty$. Then, by the uniqueness of the limit, if I can see that $\{f_n\}$ is Cauchy in $L^2$, then I can conclude the proof. But I could not show that $\|f_n- f_m\|_{L^{2}}\to0$ as $n,m\to\infty$.

I appreciate any advice.

Comment: ??? You say you're trying to show $f_n\to f$ in $L^2$. Then you say you can get $f_n\to f$ in $L^2$.

Comment: Anyway: Plancherel.

Comment: Yes, I want to show $f_n \to f$ in $L^2$. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: It would be good if you tried to explain the confusion. You say you can get exactly what you say you're trying to prove. So what's the problem?

Comment: Maybe I was in the wrong direction. I tried to show that $f_n$ is Cauchy in $L^2$. This and the uniqueness give the desired convergence i.e. $f_n\to f$ in $L^2$.

Comment: That has nothing to do with what I'm confused about. Read your post. You say "I'm trying to prove P". Then you say "I can get P". This makes no sense - you _say_ that you've _solved_ the problem you're asking about! It must be that you didn't mean exactly what you wrote, or something.

Comment: I am so sorry for making you confused. Let me explain. What I can get is just $f_n\rightharpoonup f$ not $f_n \to f$.

Comment: Oh. The two statements are not the same, sorry. I have no idea what the difference between $\rightharpoonup$ and $\to$ is; I assumed they were the same.

Comment: No problem. Roughly speaking, "$\rightharpoonup$" is weaker than "$\to$" in general. But Plancherel may help me solve my problem. Thank you.

Comment: [Sigh] That doesn't explain what they actually mean...

Comment: My bad. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_convergence_(Hilbert_space)

Comment: You could have just said it means weak convergence. I've never seen that notation. Whatever. It's very easy to show that $||f||_{L^2}\le||f||_{H^1}$ using the Fourier transform.

Comment: My apologies. I agree with $\|f\|_{L^2}\le\|f\|_{H^1}$, but $f_n$ is not Cauchy in $H^1$.

Comment: Oh! Now that I understand the notation I should have re-read the problem. It's not as trivial  as it appeared at first... Hmm, actually it seems false - I'm not sure, not having verified the details carefully and not having a good feeling for what weak convergence in $H^1$ "really means", but: Say $f_0\in H^1(\mathbb R)$ and $f_n(t)=f(t-n)$. Isn't  it clear that $f_n$ tends to $0$ weakly in $H^1$? If yes that's a counterexample.

Comment: Now I feel it seems false too. But it is not clear to me that $f_n$ tends to $0$ weakly in $H^1$... Your example seems to be a counterexample.

Comment: Well, $H^1$ is informally "one (weak) derivative in L^2",  right? Is it correct to say that the, or an, inner product defining the $H^1$ norm is $<f,g> = \int f\overline g + \int f'\overline {g'}$? If yes then $f_n$ does tend to $0$ weakly.

Comment: Yes, your inner product is actually true (mathematically).

Comment: Or, maybe cleaner: $H^1=\{f:\hat f\in L^2(1+\xi^2)d\xi\}$, so the inner product is just the inner product in that $L^2$ space, applied to the Fourier transforms. So the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma shows that $f_n\to0$ weakly in $H^1$.

Comment: Was there some good reason to think it was true, like it says so in some book?

Comment: Ah: It's true on the circle.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand\tow\rightharpoonup$ (In case I'm not the only one who was not familiar with the notation: We're using "$\tow$" to denote weak convergence.)

The suggested implication is false. It's true on the torus $\mathbb T^d$. We give the counterexample and the proof in one dimension; the higher-dimensional case is the same except for notation.

Say $f_0\in H^1(\mathbb R)$, $f_0\ne0$. Define $$f_n(t)=f_0(t-n).$$ The sequence $(f_n)$ is certainly not (norm) convergent in $L^2$, but it's clear that $f_n\tow0$ in $H^1$.

Or if it's not clear,  note that $H^1$ is a Hilbert space with inner product $$<f,g>=\int f\overline g+\int f'\overline{g'}$$(where $f,g,f',g'\in L^2$ and the derivatives are weak derivatives in any of various senses.)

Suppose now that $f_n\tow0$ in $H^1(\mathbb T)$. Uniform Boundedness implies that $||f_n||_{H^1}$ is bounded; in particular $$\sum_k k^2|\hat f_n(k)|^2\le c$$for all $n$. Since $\lim_n\hat f_n(k)=0$ for all $k$ this makes it clear that $||f_n||_{L^2}\to0$.

In more detail: Let $\epsilon>0$. Choose $A$ so $c/A^2<\epsilon/2$. Then
$$\sum_{|k|\ge A}|\hat f_n(k)|^2<\epsilon/2$$for every $n$. But $\lim_n\hat f_n(k)=0$ for every $k$, so there exists $N$ such that 
$$\sum_{|k|<A}|\hat f_n(k)|^2<\epsilon/2\quad(n>N).$$

**Oops** Just realized that $\lim_n\hat f_n(k)=0$ is not quite as obvious as I thought, because the inner product is not just $\int f\overline g$. But it's ok: Let $e_k(t)=e^{ikt}$. Then $$<f_n,e_k>=\hat f_n(k)-ik\widehat{f_n'}(k)=(1+k^2)\hat f_n(k),$$so $\lim_n<f_n,e_k>=0$ implies $\lim_n\hat f_n(k)=0$.

**Conjecture** The result is true for $H^1(\Omega)$, if $\Omega$ is a *bounded* open set in $\mathbb R^d$.

This can't be quite as simple as the argument above, since we don't have those Fourier coefficients to play with. But:

**Hand-Waving** If not there exists a sequence with $f_n\tow0$ in $H^1(
\Omega)$ but $||f_n||_{L^2}\ge1$. This is impossible. Roughly, if $f_n\tow0$ then either $|f_n|^2$ must have some mass wandering off to the boundary or $f_n$ must have a lot of oscillation; in either case $||f_n'||_{L^2}$ must be unbounded, contradicting $f_n\tow0$.

I wouldn't be surprised if that could be made into a proof. I've got class soon...